# Android NavigationDrawer overlap by status bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, statusbar

I've seen a lot questions about having a translucent status bar on top of navigation bar like this:

[image]

But what I want to achieve is to have a non-translucent status bar and make navigation drawer header view same height as action bar. This works find for pre-lollipop devices (API < 21). But for API 21+, the entire navigation drawer just moved up and overlapped by status bar, instead of place below status bar. The only work around I can think of is to manually set `layout_marginTop` on the header view for devices later than API 21+. Is there a better solution to fix this for all devices?

API < 21:

[image]

API > 21:

[image]

styles.xml(v21):

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

DrawerLayout:

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've tried to set `fitsSystemWindows` to both `true` or `false`. No changes.

Here is my hack solution when initialize navigation drawer (and this is also answered by @AkashBhave):

```
    LinearLayout navigationHeader = (LinearLayout) navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // This is make sure navigation header is below status bar
        // This only required for devices API >= 21
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) navigationHeader.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
        navigationHeader.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that `fitsSystemWindows` is set to `false` not only in your `NavigationView` but also in your root `DrawerLayout` element as well as in any of your content layouts.

I struggled with this problem for a while until I noticed an `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` which has been set in my old root layout element before I wrapped it up inside the `DrawerLayout`.

I removed all occurences of `android:fitsSystemWindows` and the status bar got respected for API 21+ as well.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

      <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.ImprintActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            >

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_logo_small"/>

          </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_imprint"/>

      </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

      <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view_menu"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Removing fitsSystemWindows is not resolving the problem version 30 Android

Answer (score 7):

Add -> In `DrawerLayout`:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

and in `NavigationView`:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. Can you tell me what's the problem and how does it solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, this worked out for me also, but yes it would be nice to get some explanations

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just set a `margin_top` attribute to devices higher than API 21 +. You can retrieve the system API level with:

```
Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
```

This is how you could check for it and set it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks. This is what I did. But I thought there maybe a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't think there is. I tried searching for one but I didn't find one. I think this is as good as it gets (and its not too bad).

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the status bar color to transparent when the drawer is opened -

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  **android:fitsSystemWindows="false"**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```